# power bi DAX hierarchical table concatenation of names

Tags: powerbi, dax, hierarchical

Since two days I'm on a problem and I can't solve it so I come here to ask some help...
I have that bit of dax that basically take the path of a hierarchical table (integers) and take the string names of the 2 first in the path.

the names I use:

- 'HIERARCHY' the hierarchical table with names, id, path, nbrItems, string
- mytable / addedcolumn1/2 the new table used to emulate the for loop

```
DisplayPath =
    var __Path =PATH(ParentChild[id], ParentChild[parent_id])
    var __P1 = PATHITEM(__Path,1) var __P2 = PATHITEM(__Path,2)
    var l1 = LOOKUPVALUE(ParentChild[Place],ParentChild[id],VALUE(__P1))
    var l2a = LOOKUPVALUE(ParentChild[Place],ParentChild[id],VALUE(__P2))
    var l2 = if(ISBLANK(l2a), "", " -> " & l2a) 
return CONCATENATE(l1,l2)
```

My problem is... I don't know the number of indexes in my path, can go from 0 to I guess 15...
I've tried some things but can't figure out a solution.
First I added a new column called nbrItems which calculate the number of items in the list of the path.

The two columns:

[image: the two columns:]

Then I added that bit of code that emulates a for loop depending on the number of items in the path list, and I'd like in it to

1. get name of parameters
2. concatenate them in one string that I can return and get

```
string = 
    var n = 'HIERARCHY'[nbrItems]
    var mytable = GENERATESERIES(1, n)
    var addedcolumn1 = ADDCOLUMNS(mytable, "nom", /* missing part: get name */)
    var addedcolumn2 = ADDCOLUMNS(addedcolumn1, "string", /* missing part: concatenate previous concatenated and new name */)
    var mymax = MAXX(addedcolumn2, [Value])
RETURN MAXX(FILTER(addedcolumn2, [Value] = mymax), [string])
```

Full table:

[image: full table]

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Can you please add some source data of your table(s). Getting confused on your terminology. Are you looking for the number of children of one node?

Comment: I let you check the update (bottom), there s an image of the full table, 
for the FOR loop I don't have any image to display... that s just a 3x X matrix with id, name, concatenated names.

Don't take attention to the names, that s from my country ;)

Comment: So what is the expected output, I can't tell from the image you upload.

Comment: for exemple, line with id 16 (path = 1 2 10 17 16) should have a "string" output like "Jean Floch -> Abattoirs -> Moreac -> Bât admin -> Conditionnement". Once again, don't care about the words, that s some french ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some research and a lot of try and error... I've came up to a nice and simple solution:
The original problem was that I had a hierarchical table ,but with all data in the same table.

[like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY3vj.png)

What I did was, adding a new "parent" column with this dax:

```
parent = 
    var a = 'HIERARCHY'[id_parent]
    var b = CALCULATE(MIN('HIERARCHY'[libelle]), FILTER(ALL('HIERARCHY'), 'HIERARCHY'[id_h] = a))
RETURN b
```

This gets the parent name from the id_parent (ref. screen).

then I could just use the path function, not on the id's but on the names... like so:

```
path = PATH('HIERARCHY'[libelle], 'HIERARCHY'[parent])
```

It made the problem easy because I didn't need to replace the id's by there names after this...

and finally to make it look nice, I used some substitution to remove the pipes:

```
formated_path = SUBSTITUTE('HIERARCHY'[path], "|", " -> ")
```

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwhfE.png)